# Show old + new state

Tags: reactjs

Im working on React task and I'm not sure how to show all persons bellow html tag h2 Numbers h2. I need to display the persons I currently have in the state + new added persons from form. Thanks in advance!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'


const App = () => {
  const [ persons, setPersons ] = useState([  { name: 'Arto Hellas' }]) 
  const [ newName, setNewName ] = useState('')

  const addName = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault()
      const nameObject = {
          name: newName,
      }
      setPersons(persons.concat(nameObject))
      setNewName('')
  }

  const handleNameChange = (event) => {
      console.log(event.target.value);
      setNewName(event.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Phonebook</h2>
      <form onSubmit={addName} >
        <div>
          name: <input value={newName} onChange={handleNameChange} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <h2>Numbers</h2>
          {persons.name}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Wouldn't you add the new person to the state?

Comment: @DBS sorry what you mean?

Comment: @Norby `persons` state is an `array` ... and you're dealing with it as `string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `persons` is an `array`, then you can do this:-

- adding new `person` in `persons` array:-

```
const addName = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  const nameObject = {
    name: newName,
  }
  setPersons([nameObject, ...persons]) // adding new person without leaving current persons in the array
  setNewName('')
}
```

- displaying `persons`(use `.map()` since `persons` is an `array`. You can't just display it like , `{person.name}`):-

```
<h2>Numbers</h2>
{persons.map(person => (
  <p key={person.name}>{person.name}</p>
))}
```